# FPDF error: Some data has already been output by using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am getting FPDF Error while trying to OutPut

```
    require('cons.php');  
    $fpd = new fpdfx();
    $fpd->AddPage();
    $fpd->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $fpd->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $fpd->Output();
```

and i have few codes in cons.php

```
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); //For Error Reporting        
        session_start();
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'da_DK');
        set_time_limit(0);
        define("DBHOST","XXX");
        define("DBNAME","XXX");
        define("DBUSER","XXX");
        define("DBPASS","XXX");       
        define("TODAYSDATE",date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+4 months")));
        define("UPDATEDATE",date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+5 months")));       
        define("LanguageFilesURL",'XXX');   

        global $instance;
        require("inc/Email-class.php");
        require("inc/database_class.php");
```

email class have email functionality with some email functions

here is my Email Class details

```
                require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
                class fpdfx extends FPDF
                {

                }


                class Email_class
                {
                }
```

when i am trying to get some output its shows

**FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out the $fpd->Output(); and see if you got any notice or other data sent sent to the output.

If not, dig into the Output() method and use die(); until you find what puts some data out!

Comment: case 'D':  
// Download file  
$this->_checkoutput();  
header('Content-Type: application/x-download');  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');  
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');  
header('Pragma: public');  
echo $this->buffer;  
die();  
break;  Like this ??

Comment: Have you tried to just comment out the $fpd->Output(); ? And inside the Output() method, you should die; before headers are sent, and see if anything has been output already.

Comment: yeah i tried both not working anymore, // Download file
   $this->_checkoutput();
   //header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
   //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
   //header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
   //header('Pragma: public');
   die();
   echo $this->buffer;

Comment: i comment all headers from OutPut function

Comment: You could just die(); before headers are sent. Your goal is to find out what's written to the output before FPDF headers are sent.

Comment: after die() i got %PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœ3Rðâ2Ð35W(çr QÐw3T04Ó30PISp  êZ*˜[š€…¤(hx¤æää+„çå¤(j*„dÔ7W endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 5 0 R >>

Comment: Weird, the die; should prevent echoing $this->buffer... Anyway, an other thing you can try is remove all closing PHP tags from your included files. There may be a hidden character sent to the outpup when a file is included.